# Time Series Analysis, choosing best model, python

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I am new at timeseries modelling. 
I have a data set containing Weeknumber (1 to 52), 3 dummy variables for 3 season summer, autumn and spring, promotion_dummy (yes or no) and Sales for the weeks.
I have to forecast Sales for next 10 weeks. 
[I have attached a picture of sample data]

Which model to use?

Comment: Have you considered asking on [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com)? Also, you should try to show some attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: your choice of model depends on what you are trying to achieve. Also as mentioned already it would be helpfull if you some code you have already tried